# Outlook messages appearing multiple times in conversation view

Tags: microsoft-outlook

These are not duplicate messages, but they are displayed multiple times.

All 6 messages are in the folder from which I'm viewing them.

[image: Conversation view showing duplicate messages]

Answer (score 0):

This only happens when I first change a folder view from some standard one (like "Compact") to my personalized one (although both views use conversation mode).

When I switch to a different folder and then come back, the view resolves itself, and no longer displays duplication.

Although an issue, it's not significant if you know to just switch between folders to resolve it. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing~